# discord.py: How to go back to in a command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command and in this command the bot waits for a message. In this case for the message content "No" or "Yes". But if the user writes something else, the bot sends a message, that this not work and the user sould try again. So in this case the bot should check again, if the user sends "No" or "Yes". But how can I do this?

My Code:

```
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx, choice = None):
    if choice == 'welcome':
        def check4(messagetitletags):
            return messagetitletags.channel.id == ctx.message.channel.id and messagetitletags.author == ctx.message.author and not messagetitletags.author == ctx.message.author.bot

        messagetitletagscheck = await client.wait_for('message', check=check4, timeout=None)

        if messagetitletagscheck.content in ['Yes', 'y', 'Y', 'yes']:
            with open(r'./welcome.json', 'r') as f:
                welcomemessage = json.load(f)
            if f'{ctx.guild.id}' in welcomemessage.keys():
                try:
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f'TitleTags'] = {}
                    welcomemessage[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f"TitleTags"] = f"Yes"
                except KeyError:
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f'TitleTags'] = {}
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"TitleTags"] = f"Yes"
            else:
                welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = {}
                welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"TitleTags"] = [f"Yes"]
            with open(r'./welcome.json', 'w+')as f:
                json.dump(welcomemessage, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

        elif messagetitletagscheck.content in ['No', 'n', 'N', 'no']:
            with open(r'./welcome.json', 'r') as f:
                welcomemessage = json.load(f)
            if f'{ctx.guild.id}' in welcomemessage.keys():
                try:
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f'TitleTags'] = {}
                    welcomemessage[f'{ctx.guild.id}'][f"TitleTags"] = f"No"
                except KeyError:
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f'TitleTags'] = {}
                    welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"TitleTags"] = f"No"
            else:
                welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = {}
                welcomemessage[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"TitleTags"] = [f"No"]
            with open(r'./welcome.json', 'w+')as f:
                json.dump(welcomemessage, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

        else:
            await ctx.send('<:error:713187214586282054> Invalid input. Please try again.')
            return check4
```

Comment: You can use a while loop that stays true. Until the outcome is succesfull.

Comment: Can you do an example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a while loop that loops till the outcome is successfull.

For example if you want to wait for a valid yes/no answer you can make the statement false on correct output.

Example:

```
def your_code():
    if output == "right":
        # some code
        return True
    elif output == "wrong":
        # some code
        return True
    else:
        # some code
        return False

answer_is_valid = False

while not answer_is_valid: # Loops till answer_is_valid is True
    answer_is_valid = your_code() # This puts the return value in answer_is_valid.
                                  #If the return value was False it will loop again.
```

I dont recommend it to loop forever if the users constantly returns incorrect input. So I would put another check in the function that stops the function after x tries.
This can look like this:

```
def your_code():
    if output == "right":
        # some code
        return True
    elif output == "wrong":
        # some code
        return True
    else:
        # some code
        return False

answer_is_valid = False
incorrect_tries = 0
max_incorrect_tries = 5

# the loops exits if the answer is valid. Or max incorrect tries has been reached    
while not answer_is_valid and incorrect_tries <= max_incorrect_tries:
    answer_is_valid = your_code() # This repeats the function until the function returns True
    incorrect_tries += 1
```

You can replace the your_code() function with your function make sure to return True/False if the output is correct/incorrect.

To implement it:

```
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx, choice = None):
    if choice == "welcome":
         # some code
```

should be converted to:

```
def welcome():
    # some code that returns True when the input was valid, False if not

@client.command()
async def setup(ctx, choice = None):
    if choice == "welcome":
        # the new code with while loop explained earlier using your welcome function
```